# How to create a "next"/"previous" that will shows more products?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building an eCommerce site. I have a bunch of products, and I don't want buyers to keep scrolling down to view more products. I ideally would like about 10 products per page.

I have created a next/previous button, and its all I have so far.

```
<button onclick="location.href='nextpage.html'">next page</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep all the products on one page and then put them all in a slider such as this, which will encompass ten products.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide all DIVs wrapped within .carousel
    $('.carousel div').hide();
    /**
     * Show first slide
     * If you want to display another child, just replace
     * :first-child by :nth-child(n) where n is an integer
     */
    $('.carousel div:first-child').show();
    // Hide previous button if we're on the first slide
    if( $('.carousel div:visible').is(':first-child') ) {
        $('.btn-prev').hide();
    }
    // Listen button clicks
    $('.btn-dir').click(function(){
        // Hide next button on the last slide
        if( $('.carousel div:visible').next().is(':last-child') ) {
            $('.btn-next').hide();
        }
        // If button next is clicked display next slide
        if( $(this).attr('class') == 'btn-dir btn-next' ) {
            if( $('.carousel div:visible').next().length > 0 ) {
                $('.btn-prev').show();
                $('.carousel div:visible').toggle().next().toggle();
            }
        }
        // If button prev is clicked display previous slide
        if( $(this).attr('class') == 'btn-dir btn-prev' ) {
            if( $('.carousel div:visible').prev().length > 0 ) {
                $('.btn-next').show();
                $('.carousel div:visible').toggle().prev().toggle();
            }
            // If we reached the first slide, hide prev button
            if( $('.carousel div:visible').is(':first-child') ) {
                $('.btn-prev').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
button {
    border: none;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.carousel.expose-left {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-5%);
}
.carousel.expose-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5%);
}
.carousel.move-left {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
.carousel.move-right {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.slide {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.slide-img {
    display: block;
}
.fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.btn-dir {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.btn-next {
    right: 0;
}
.btn-prev {
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slide slide-left">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ab003c/ffffff&text=Product 1" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-middle">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/00ad8a/ffffff&text=Product 2" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/ab6100/ffffff&text=Product 3" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/557FFF/ffffff&text=Product 4" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/FFAA55/ffffff&text=Product 5" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/7F2AFF/ffffff&text=Product 6" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/2AFF7F/ffffff&text=Product 7" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/D4FF00/ffffff&text=Product 8" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/FF2AFF/ffffff&text=Product 9" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/7FFFFF/ffffff&text=Product 10" alt="" class="slide-img fluid" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="direction">
    <button class="btn-dir btn-next">></button>
    <button class="btn-dir btn-prev"><</button>
</div>
```